# Passport-Facebook On Sails. No facebook login page

Tags: node.js, facebook, sails.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

Sails Version: 0.12.13
Node Version: 7.10.1

My Auth Controller:

```
facebookSignin: function (req,res,next){
    passport.authenticate('facebook',{scope : 'email'})(req, res, next);
},
facebookCallback: function (req,res){
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login' })
},
```

Passport.js

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    clientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:1337/api/v1/auth/facebook/callback"
},
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    }
));
```

Routes.js

```
'get /api/v1/auth/facebookSignin': 'AuthController.facebookSignin',
'get /api/v1/auth/facebook/callback':'AuthController.facebookCallback',
```

On the call to this auth function no login page is displayed.

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1337%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=basic_info%2Cemail&client_id=XXXXXXXXX. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Comment: You can not load the Facebook login dialog via AJAX, you have to redirect the user there in the top window instance.